# Can't figure out why the code crashes in C++

Tags: c++

The compiler just crashes when I try to run the code and I can't find the problem.

I get this error: `0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000`.
So it must be a pointer error.

But I can't seem to figure out what I did wrong. So if someone can help me it would be very appreciated.

**classB.ccp**

```
ClassB::ClassB(ClassC *CPtr, int x)
{
    ClassC *CPtr_ = CPtr;
    x_ = x;
}

void ClassB::print() const
{
    CPtr_->print();
    std::cout << x_ << std::endl;
}
```

**ClassC.ccp**

```
ClassC::ClassC(int y)
{
    y_ = y;
}

void ClassC::print() const
{
    std::cout << y_ << std::endl;
}
```

**main**

```
ClassC myCObject(7);
ClassB myBObject(&myCObject , 11);
myBObject.print();
```

Comment: The typical extension for C++ files is `.cpp`, not `.ccp`.

Comment: Does it compile i.e. `x_ = x;` Where is `x_` declared

Comment: In ClassB constructor you store the pointer to a local variable. You probably want to store it into objrct's member!

Comment: The *compiler* crashes ? Or your code crashes ?

Comment: CPtr_ in the constructor is the local variable which is getting assigned, while CPtr_ in ClassB::print() is member variable which contains garbage value, so code is crashing.
Modify this line ClassC *CPtr_ = CPtr; to CPtr_ = CPtr;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the constructor of class `ClassB` you stored the parameter value `CPtr` in a *local variable* `CPtr_`. Why did you do that?

Apparently, the idea was to store in the data member `CPtr_` of `ClassB`. Yet, for some unexplainable reason, you decided to declare a local variable with the same name in the constructor. Because of that extra variable, the data member remains uninitialized (contains garbage) and the code crashes when you attempt to dereference it.

Answer (score 3):

Here, `CPtr_` is a local variable. I guess that you would like to store `CPtr` in an attribute of `ClassB`. Maybe there is one, and the local variable shadows it.

```
ClassB::ClassB(ClassC *CPtr, int x)
{
    ClassC *CPtr_ = CPtr;
    x_ = x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ClassB::ClassB(ClassC *CPtr, int x)
{
    ClassC *CPtr_ = CPtr;
    x_ = x;
}
```

when you call your constructor you're creating a ClassC pointer, but when the constructor ends that pointer is destroyed becouse it's a local variable

add your

```
ClassC *CPtr_;
```

var to the definition of your class, then, the constructor must look something like

```
ClassB::ClassB(ClassC *CPtr, int x)
{
    CPtr_ = CPtr;
    x_ = x;
}
```